# Multi-Dimensional Arrays in Ractive.js

Tags: javascript, view, multidimensional-array, ractivejs

I've been playing around with the fantastic Ractive.js library (not to be confused with Facebook's *Reactive*.js). I worked out that you can render a two-dimensional using the following template code:

```
<div class="container">
{{ #frameContainer:i }}
    <div class="row">
    {{ #frameContainer[i] }}
        <div on-click="cell-click" class="cell {{ . ? 'on' : 'off' }}"></div>
    {{ /frameContainer[] }}
    </div>
{{ /frameContainer }}
</div>
```

This works exactly as I'd expect and the inner `cell-click` event returns the correct keypath (e.g. `frameContainer.2.4`).

I then wanted to turn this into a three-dimensional array (to add a "time" axis). However, the following did not work:

```
<div class="container">
{{ #frameContainer[time]:i }}
    <div class="row">
    {{ #frameContainer[time][i] }}
        <div on-click="cell-click" class="cell {{ . ? 'on' : 'off' }}"></div>
    {{ /frameContainer[][] }}
    </div>
{{ /frameContainer }}
</div>
```

Where `time` represents the current time value (it will only ever show one "time" at a time - seems obvious when you say it like that...).

This... sort of works. It displays the grid as it should, but the returned keypath for the `cell-click` event is no longer correct, returning something like `${frameContainer-time-8-}.2` - which has lost the `time` value (and has gone a bit weird).

Obviously I could just do it by having a `currentFrame` value which I render from and switch around with `ractive.set()`, but that seems less elegant. Is there a way to do it purely within the template? And, if not, what's the most efficient way of doing it otherwise?

Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is quite a tricky one. Basically, the `${frameContainer-time-8-}` keypath is how Ractive uniquely identifies an [expression](http://docs.ractivejs.org/latest/expressions), and  `${frameContainer-time-8-}.2` means 'the third member of whatever that expression evaluates to'.

What's happening here is this: When Ractive's parser sees the `{{ #frameContainer[time][i] }}` section, it parses `frameContainer[time][i]` as a JavaScript expression and turns it into the following (you can try this yourself - `Ractive.parse('{{#frameContainer[time][i]}}')`):

```
{
  r: ['i','time','frameContainer'],
  s: '${2}[${1}][${0}]'
}
```

When the template is rendered, Ractive creates an *evaluator* for that expression, which has a function generated from the string (the `s` property), and which watches the `time` and `frameContainer` values (it doesn't need to watch `i` because it can't change). When either or both of those values change, the function is executed with them as arguments. If it returns a changed value, Ractive needs to update the view.

Since there's a good mechanism for propagating viewmodel changes to the view - keypaths - that's what the evaluator uses. In order to do so, it needs to create a unique keypath, hence `${frameContainer-time-8-}` (it can't contain dots or square brackets, because Ractive would try to split on those).

So here's the thing: expression keypaths are one-way. You can't do `ractive.set('${frameContainer-time-8-}.2', 'true')` like you can with regular keypaths, because Ractive can't figure out what underlying property that corresponds to (or if there even is one - it might be a derivative value for all it knows).

### Solution 1

The simplest workaround would probably be to do something like this:

```
<div on-click="cell-click:{{time}},{{i}}" class="cell {{ . ? 'on' : 'off' }}"></div>
```

You can then use the `time` and `i` values in your `cell-click` handler (they will be the second and third arguments, after `event`).

I've done a simplified demo here (assuming I understood you correctly): http://jsfiddle.net/rich_harris/LYEGX/

### Solution 2

The other way would be to do away with keypaths altogether and use an adaptor. I won't go into all the details here as it may not be the answer you're looking for, but there's some [documentation](http://docs.ractivejs.org/latest/adaptors) and an [example](http://examples.ractivejs.org/backbone) (some of the links are currently out of date, sorry...). In short, this method assumes you're able to use non-POJOs in your app.

Comment: Solution #1 work brilliantly. Amazing how little code is needed!